# Get device name of Konica Minolta Bizhub with curl in bash script

Tags: xml, bash, shell, curl

I'm trying to get device name from Konica Minolta Bizhub C364.

When I type *curl ip-addr* of this printer I receive this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN">
<HTML lang="en">
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<meta content="text/javascript" http-equiv="Content-Script-Type">
<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/wcd/js_error.xml">
</noscript>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#ffffff" LINK="#000000" ALINK="#ff0000" VLINK="#000000" onload="location.replace('/wcd/index.html?access=SYS_INF');" >
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Calling curl with link in *onload location.replace* also doesn't work.
On view page source in Chrome browser I receive full XML info with device name and model etc.
My question is how to call curl command to get this XML or HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this url:

/OpenAPI/DeviceDescription/

You will get an XML with a lot of useful information.